# CouchDB getJSON not returnng what I expected

Tags: jquery, couchdb, getjson

I have a test account on iriscouch

I am trying to write a routine to process the JSON returned.

```
function getMyJson(url) {
    $('#dispJson').html('<h3>Json Data from: ' + url);
    data = $.getJSON(url);
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $('#dispJson').append('key: ' + key + ' Val: ' +  val + '<br />');
    });
    return true;
};
```

But I appear to be getting JSON back, but not what I was expecting

Results

```
key: readyState Val: 1
key: setRequestHeader Val: function ( name, value ) { if ( !state ) { var lname = name.toLowerCase(); name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name; requestHeaders[ name ] = value; } return this; }
key: getAllResponseHeaders Val: function () { return state === 2 ? 
......
jQuery.type( elem ); if ( type === "array" ) { deferred.done.apply( deferred, elem ); } else if ( type === "function" ) { callbacks.push( elem ); } } if ( _fired ) { deferred.resolveWith( _fired[ 0 ], _fired[ 1 ] ); } } return this; }
key: statusCode Val: function ( map ) { if ( map ) { var tmp; if ( state < 2 ) { for( tmp in map ) { statusCode[ tmp ] = [ statusCode[tmp], map[tmp] ]; } } else { tmp = map[ jqXHR.status ]; jqXHR.then( tmp, tmp ); } } return this; }
```

In fact I get that response from whatever url I use on the IrisCouch site.

I have JSONP set to true and I also tested with ?callback=? appended to the URL.

I am hoping someone recognises the output I am getting and can advise me as to what I have misunderstood or done wrong.

Thanks mcl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `data` to the XHR object returned by jQuery.  Remember that XHR is asynchronous so you can't expect the result to be immediately available.

Instead, you should be doing something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('#dispJson').append('key: ' + key + ' Val: ' +  val + '<br />');
        });
    }
});
```

Be sure to read through the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the link and the code.  I have tried your suggestion, but I do not seem to be getting any output now.  The output I get from the url in a browser is as follows: `{"db_name":"arthur1","doc_count":4,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":17,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":266329,"instance_start_time":"1318541528171594","disk_format_version":5,"committed_update_seq":17}`

Comment: I think it may be something to do with the `url: url` because I am now getting a Not Found Error (404), which has prefixed the [object] with my domain name.  As you must realise, I am struggling with this, because it is trying to learn so many concepts at the same time.  Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: "url" should be the value you passed in with getMyJson(url).  Can you do an `alert(url)` or `console.log(url)` right before the `$.getJSON` line and see if that is the value you expected?  It should be a string.

Comment: It is the correct url `http://sitename.iriscouch.com/dbname`, which I have displayed in an `<H3>` and copied and pasted to the browser, to check it works OK.  But I get this error in the Chrome Console `Window GET http://mydomain.net/ArthurCouch/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` I do not understand this error and I am wondering why it is displaying the prefix of my script, which is in the subdirectory ArthurCrouch.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Try the above code now. `$.getJSON` doesn't accept the data structure I was passing.  I prefer to just use `$.ajax` for everything since its more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks. It is now working as I expected. The dataType does need to be specified as 'jsonp' (I think because it is a cross domain access) and I added type 'get' for my clarity.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myurl,    // eg http://mysite.iriscouch.com/mydatabase or whatever valid curl command
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('#dispJson').append('key: ' + key + ' Val: ' +  val + '<br />');
        });
    }
});
```

Just need to figure out how to identify Values as arrays and then process them.  I imagine I could end up with many levels and somewhere there is a beautiful hierarchical tree routine that does it all. But hey, we have to learn it from scratch.

Thanks again